# get android.jar (API 21) artifact

Tags: android, maven, android-5.0-lollipop

I need to use Android API 21 (Lollipop) classes. I am using maven to build my Android project. I know I need to define dependency in order to build my project. So I defined the following one:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
     <artifactId>android</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
     <version>4.1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But the above latest artifact doesn't contain the support for Android API 21, also [maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.android%22) shows me there is no artifact available for Android API 21 (Lollipop).

In order to make the maven build work, I am thinking to get the artifact jar & install it in my local maven repository.

My question is where can I download the android.jar artifact of Android API 21 (Lollipop) ? If there is no place to download it, what could be a workaround for my maven build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are better ways to solve this from a Maven point of view, but since the question was where you can download the android.jar artifact, here's a solution to that. You can download the [stand-alone Android SDK tools](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools) and then use SDK Manager to download your desired version of the Android SDK. Once you've downloaded it you'll find the android.jar under ./platforms/android-21/

Comment: Thanks, actually I figured it out almost the same time when you press "answer" button :)

Comment: Glad it worked out. Please close the question by either accepting my answer or providing your own answer.